# How to export data from Google BigQuery to PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql, google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I have a table stored in BigQuery and I would like to create a copy of this table+data within a PostgreSQL database. This PostgreSQL is in Google Cloud SQL.

This export will occur daily, that is, the same table will be exported daily to PostgreSQL, so the ideal solution can be automated/repeated, rather than a manual solution.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: The title of this question is incorrect. You want to export a table. There is a huge difference between exporting a table and exporting data. I'm mainly interested in exporting the entire database and found your question as well as the answer useless.

Comment: @Ash The title is not incorrect. Your interpretation is correct. Data != database. Data is a vague mass noun, so could refer to anything, which OP defines in their question. But you wanted more than just 'data' from the outset; you wanted an _entire database_. That's not OP's fault nor the answerer's fault. The question and answer are clear and correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the BigQuery and CloudSQL APIs to do that, [exporting the BQ table as CSV](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/exporting-data#exporting_table_data) to cloud storage and then [importing the file as table in CloudSQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/docs/postgres/import-export/import-export-csv#import). Then you can automate this process using Cloud Functions + Cloud Scheduler (or even [Cloud DataFlow](https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs) for more complex pipelines).

Comment: I read that Bigquery has the "EXPORT DATA" command which allows you to export data to a file, for example CSV. Do you consider this command as a solution to export data using only SQL syntax? That is, without using Python or another language? On the part of Postgres, I don't know if there is any SQL command from Postgres that would allow reading a CSV file directly from Cloud Storage

Comment: This answer would be improved by showing, at least in part, _how_ to "use the Big Query and Cloud SQL APIs to do that".